# Excel Getting Floating point number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a excel sheet that has some values something like below.

[image: My Excel sheet]

When I want to get the values by concatenating with a string, points are being erased. The cells format are Number by the way.

If I do `=P3` , it gets me `27.655.111`

When I do `="(test '"&P3&"')"`, it gets me `(test '27655111')`. This is not correct. I need the points in the number.

How to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: These aren't floating point numbers, they're thousands-separated numbers. So `P3` is equal to 27,655,111 (written the American way).

Comment: Then how to get the seperators ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `="(test '"& TEXT(P3;"#.##0") & "')"`.
Replace the **;** by a **,** according to your regional settings.
Replace #.##0 by any format string as desired.

Comment: This is what I wanted. I will mark it when I can. Thanks